# I'm unable to Capture Select2 Events - I suspect I'm using the wrong jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

This is the javascript I've written - it alerts me that four `.select2` instances were found and four `select` elements were found and logs a message to the console, but no amount of changing what I have selected from the select2 boxes is actually logging or alerting me about changes. I suspect I'm using the wrong selector for finding the objects to attach these `change` listeners to, but I can't find a complete example in the documentation for how to find my `select2` elements.

```
$(document).on('change', '.select2-input', function(e) {
    console.log('Detected a different change!');
    alert('The other method of detecting changes worked!');
});
$('.select2').on('change', function(e) {
    console.log('Detected a change!');
    alert('Something was changed!');
});
console.log('Loaded!');
alert('Loaded v2 - found ' + $('.select2').length + ' instances of select2 and ' + $('select').length + ' instances of select.');
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to find the select2 internal controls (`.select2-input`) - use the select2 events that are provided: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#listening-for-events

Comment: @freedomn-m - The examples on that page are incomplete, but they show finding the select2 instance by id (`#mySelect2`). I don't create the select2 instances though or have their ID (and unless I'm looking at the wrong thing in the dom, I don't think they have IDs at all...). I have no idea - how do I generally just listen to all events from all select2 instances on my website, regardless of what library or framework made them? I'm using jquery so answers using it are fine.

Comment: Not the clearest samples.  `#mySelect2` would be the id of the original `<select>`.  here's a sample using an event: https://jsfiddle.net/y52tuvam/  In this fiddle I've used an id, in the SO wiki tag they've used a class, but it's whatever you use when you convert your `select` initially `$("select").select2()`

Comment: *I don't create the select2 instances* - how are the select2 instances created?

Comment: @freedomn-m - On my server, I'm using `Django`, `dal`, and `dal_select2` - those together are rendering the fields of a Django form into a `select2` element that as far as I know, I have little control over. I'd like to show/hide fields as users change their selections in the `select2` boxes, and I decided catching these events was probably the best way to do it. I don't think all that complexity is relevant. I'll look into the answer you gave and see what I can do with it - I do have the source of `dal_select2` so I can see it calls `$(...).select2()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to find my select2 elements

This is the same selector that you use when you convert your `select` to a select2, eg:

```
$('.my-select-dropdown').select2();
```

> I don't create the select2 instances

In the case where the select2 is being generated elsewhere, you can find the original `select` that select2 has been applied to using:

```
$(".select2-hidden-accessible")
```

The key bit of info is that the events are raised against the *original* `select` dropdown rather than any of the select2 controls, example:

```js
// this happens elsewhere that you don't have control over
$('.select2').select2();

// find the original "converted" drop downs
$('.select2-hidden-accessible').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    console.log(data.id, data.text, $(".select2").val());
});
```

```css
.select2 { width: 150px }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My misunderstanding was I thought I was looking for events on some new `select2` element that was just evading me in the DOM - I didn't realize I could get the `change` events from the ordinary `select` elements, like you said. I switched to using `$('.select2-hidden-accessible').on('change', ...` and now it's working as expected.